# passing parameters among ADF activities

Tags: u-sql, azure-data-factory

I have the following scenario. I need to check if certain file exists in a ADLS. If it is not, I have to send an email notifying such an absence. If it is in there, continue with the copy of it. All this uing a pipe in ADF.

I was thinking to use u-sql code to generate an output parameter, for instance, a flag(1/0). In the following activity, using an "IF" Conditional activity, check whether it is in there(1) or not(0)? copy or send email.

How can I create such output parameter from the u-sql activity, and "pass it" to the following ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify global parameter ADF pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118575/modify-global-parameter-adf-pipeline)

Comment: See answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118575/modify-global-parameter-adf-pipeline. This is a duplicate from an answer point of view.